# Cleaning Spark HttpFileServer tmp directory

Tags: java, apache-spark

Basically I have long running Spark application which executes few 1000s of Spark jobs on Hadoop cluster(with YARN resource manager). The application is being run from Eclipse, using `yarn-client` mode. After some time the tmp directory on my local machine is being filled with jar sent along the jobs and the directory is not being cleaned.

I have checked the behavior of the `ShutdownHookManager` and it seems that the temporary directories are only being cleaned on JVM shutdown, which does not happen in my case, since I use same JVM instance to run multiple jobs.

I see in log files the following line, which indicates the directory where the jars are being stored for each different job:

```
2016-03-30 15:38:22,113 [pool-1-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.spark.HttpFileServer  - HTTP File server directory is /tmp/spark-9589b88f-560a-48ef-9f42-fc7da2ecb7ee/httpd-3b9bd920-2446-43e1-bda9-de5e636ff219
```

But I am unable to find out how to detect this directory programatically, so I could clean it myself after job completion. I have been looking through the source code and it seems it was possible to get the reference to `HttpFileServer` in Spark 1.4, but not in **1.6** version.

`SparkEnv.get().sparkFilesDir()` does not work either, since it gives the the directory for user files, but it is empty (directory looks like `/tmp/spark-9589b88f-560a-48ef-9f42-fc7da2ecb7ee/userFiles-9b282866-6a27-4ab4-a093-0c134b941dd2`).

I cannot clean the `/tmp/spark-9589b88f-560a-48ef-9f42-fc7da2ecb7ee` either, since multiple jobs can be running at the same time and I can risk to delete the directory of currently active job.

So the question is, how I can find out the directory which is being pointed in logs or how I can cleanup properly the temporary files of particular jobs that finished?

Comment: This is not `spark-java` question.

Comment: @rostanek removed the tag, thanks for pointing out.